# Software to organize Wolfram Alpha searches

Tags: windows, calculator

When you do computations on your ti-89, you can scroll up to see your past calculations.

When you do a calculation on the Wolfram Alpha website, and you X out the window, you can't go find it again.

To deal with this, I've been pasting URLs + a screenshot of what I typed in into a Word doc but I'd like to find software that can save this in a more elegant and automatic way to do this to save your past calculations. The other way I thought of doing it is shoving all the URLs into the bookmarks bar but that is a bit messy and hard to navigate.

At the moment, I'm only considering the Wolfram Alpha website since it seemed to handle words and English a bit better than other calculators I've used. I'm not going to use Mathematica because I don't feel like installing it on all my devices - there should be a simpler solution for what I want which is basically saving Wolfram Alpha searches in an easy to navigate way

**What is some good software to keep a record of calculations** in case you want to go back and check if you made a mistake?

- Windows 10
- Preferably free

I've tried the extension [Save to Pocket](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/save-to-pocket/), but if you try to open a pocket from the chrome extension app, it may say that Wolfram Alpha needs java even though you already have it and can use wolfram alpha just fine on a browser.

Answer (score 2):

This may not be the answer that you are looking for but you can use [python](http://www.python.org) but the [Wolfram Alpha](https://github.com/jaraco/wolframalpha) library to query Wolfram Alpha in a repeatable manner and to save the results. If you use an [iPython](http://ipython.org/) console you can save an interactive session to a python file that you can edit/reuse and if you use a [Jupyter](http://jupyter.org/) notebook you can do all of this from within a browser window and save both query & results into a Jupyter notebook along with images, markdown text, etc. You can also export both the code and results to a number of shareable output formats *including pdf*.

- Price: All of the software mentioned above is $0.00 being gratis & open source
- Platform: All of the above is available for Windows, OS-X, Linux & more
- Installation: Quick and easy with an internet connection:

  1. Download and install python for your platform if Windows, (it is already installed on OS-X and most Linux distributions).
  2. For Wolfram Alpha library: At the Windows command prompt `pip install wolframalpha` to get and install the library and all of its dependencies, *OS-X & Linux users should use the terminal and may need to prefix with `sudo`*.
  3. For ipython: At the command line `pip install ipython` to get and install the library and all of its dependencies, *OS-X & Linux users should use the terminal and may need to prefix with `sudo`*.
  4. For Jupyter: At the command line `pip install jupyter` to get and install the library and all of its dependencies, *OS-X & Linux users should use the terminal and may need to prefix with `sudo`*.

You will need to get a developer API App ID from [Wolfram Alpha](http://products.wolframalpha.com/developers/) - it is free for personal/experimental use.

One especially nice thing about this approach *apart from reputability* is that it is not limited to Wolfram Alpha but can be used, with different APIs, for many other potential data sources.

Comment: I'll try that out later but honestly there must be something that can just save the current URLs and make it syncable across computers. I've tried a few chrome extensions to save the tabs but it doesn't sync across computers